# "The File Exist" Error on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am experiencing a strange error on Visual Studio 2015 (VB and C#) whenever I run, debug, start or even add buttons. It displays "The File Exists", I tried clearing my temp file, changing filename and target locations but it is still not working. The output windows do not display anything as well.

[image: Check image here >]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the files from your temp folder.  The location of the temp folder may change depending on your version of Windows, but it should be something like `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp`.